# Adding a default where clause to a linq-to-sql table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to add a default where clause to every SQL statement generated by a Linq-to-SQL class?

I have a custom DataContext with a Customer class.  The Customer class has a Deleted attribute, which is what I want to always be `NULL` whenever I query the table.

So for example, I could write:

```
List<Customer> customers = db.Customers.ToList<Customer>();
```

But really get:

```
List<Customer> customers = db.Customers.Where(o => o.Deleted == null).ToList<Customer>();
```

I want to maintain the "deleted" data in my DB, but will never need to see it in my .NET code.  This sort of default would be handy, so I don't have to remember to add the filter to every query.

Comment: Instead of adding the table to your dbml designer, add a view that contains the default where clause, and just name the view Customer in your dbml.

Comment: see the answer I added. I've included info about updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the table to your dbml designer, add a view that contains the default where clause, and just name the view Customer in your dbml.

To allow updates, inserts, and deletes, make sure you select the primary key columns in your DBML designer, and mark their `Primary Key` property as true.

Comment: After some more testing, I'm actually able to do inserts and updates just fine, except for when I try to update the Deleted field.  I get `ChangeConflictException - Row not found or changed.` when I call `SubmitChanges()`.  I'm guessing this is due to the fact that it's looking to the view, which does not contain that record since Deleted is no longer `null` in my DataContext's mind.

Comment: Found the issue. I had to change my computed columns from AutoSync=Always to AutoSync=Never.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new property called `ActiveCustomers` that returns this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> ActiveCustomers {
    get { return db.Customers.Where(e => e.Deleted == null); }
}
```

Any queries against that property can specify additional `Where` conditions and otherwise modify the results, but they will always be *starting* with customers who haven't been deleted. And due to LINQ's deferred execution this statement doesn't cause any additional queries to be executed.

If you need to ensure no one can access `db.Customers` you could try to hide it by doing something like this (may not work, I'd need to see your implementation):

```
public new IQueryable<Customer> Customers {
    get {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Use property ActiveCustomers instead.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when I create the `new IQueryable<Customer> Customers`, I get an ambiguity error between that and the original Customers which returns the `System.Linq.Table<Customer>`.  But I can't remove the original, because then my InsertOnSubmit calls fail, since it's trying to perform that against an `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Paul If you're using an implementation of the repository pattern you shouldn't be querying directly against a context anyway.